# Getting going on play framework - what silly mistake am I making here?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework

So I am starting out using the play framework with Mongo and have an issue with trying to get something working using the simple MVC pattern. I can't see the wood for the trees with this and know the solution is bound to be simple.

I have a user object defined as an entity:

```
package models;

import play.modules.mongo.MongoEntity;
import play.modules.mongo.MongoModel;


@MongoEntity("users")
public class User extends MongoModel
{
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

And I have a controller with the following two methods in it:

```
package controllers;

import models.User;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.Logger;

public class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public static void createUser()
    {
        User user = new User();
        render(user);     
    } 

    public static void insertUser(User iUser)
    {
        Logger.info("Paul 1: " + iUser + " :: " + (iUser ==  null));
    }

}
```

And the routes defined as follows:

```
POST    /insertUser    UserController.insertUser
GET     /users         UserController.createUser
```

So I have the following page view defined and when I click save, the code in the controller is telling me that the User object is null:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Create User' /}
<form action="@{UserController.insertUser(user)}" method="POST"/>

    Username: <input type="text" value="${user.username}" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="text" value="${user.password}" /><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" value="${user.email}" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form>
```

I have tried a ton of permutations on the acton and can't figure out why it is not working. Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated, I know it is somethign stupid I am missing, it is just what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're *at least* missing the `name` atrributes on the HTML forum input elements, which Play! will use to map the form values to your controller parameter(s). Try the following:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Create User' /}
<form action="@{UserController.insertUser(user)}" method="POST"/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user.username" value="${user.username}" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="text" name="user.password" value="${user.password}" /><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="user.email" value="${user.email}" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [template `#{form}` tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#form) to have the templating system generate the form for you. This might also be useful to cross-check the output of the `#{form}` tag with your own form to see what is different.

*Update:* you may also have to delete the `user` parameter in the form action attribute `@{UserController.insertUser(user)}`, which would then be more like `@{UserController.insertUser}`.

Comment: Sadly neither of those suggestions work. Still outputting null :-(

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rename the User class to be called UserItem. I expect there is a default User class somewhere in Mongo or Play! that was getting in the way.

Edit: Yes, including the name mappings was also instrumental in the solution although it alone did not resolve the issue. I will upvote it accordingly.

Comment: I am assuming the solution was a combination of you changing the class name, and the suggestion by @pHk, as his suggestion of using the `name` attribute in the input tag, is the only way for Play to map the http form items to the object.